# Create a zero length vector

Tags: idris

Given this type for vectors, what's the way to create a zero length vector of a particular type of items?

```
data Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type where
  VectNil : Vect 0 ty
  (::) : ty -> Vect size ty -> Vect (S size) ty
```

**VectNil String** and all the variations I've tried in the REPL failed.
Is it not correct to expect **VectNil** to work like the default constructor of the generic List in C# does?

```
new List<string> (); // creates a zero length List of string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VecNil` is value constructor and it accepts [implicit](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#implicit-arguments) type parameter. Here you can see it in REPL:

```
*x> :set showimplicits 
*x> :t VectNil 
 Main.VectNil : {ty : Type} -> Main.Vect 0 ty
```

Idris infers values of those implicit parameters from the context. But sometimes context does not have enough information:

```
*x> VectNil
(input):Can't infer argument ty to Main.VectNil
```

You can explicitly provide value for implicit parameter using braces:

```
*x> VectNil {ty=String}
Main.VectNil {ty = String} : Main.Vect 0 String
```

Or [use the `the` operator](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/repl.html#evaluating-expressions) to add a type annotation:

```
*x> the (Vect 0 String) VectNil 
Main.VectNil  : Main.Vect 0 String
```

In larger programs, Idris is able to infer the type based on its use site.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful reply.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly You can also use `the` like so: `the (Vect 0 String) VectNil`

Comment: Anton, thank you for showing me this alternative method.